# Google Kubernetes Engine Service Unable To Connect To Snowflake

Tags: google-app-engine, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, firewall

I deployed a service to GKE on Google Cloud Platform, but unfortunately, Snowflake is blocking the IP Address. I think Snowflake only enables connections to IP Addresses that have been whitelisted, so I tried creating a cluster in the appropriate Network. But when I expose the service, I still run into the error.

I have also created an App Engine instance as well in the appropriate network, and it still doesn't let me connect to Snowflake.

Error Message:

```
DatabaseError: (snowflake.connector.errors.DatabaseError) 250001 (08001): None: Failed to connect to DB: IP [XXXXXXX] is not allowed to access Snowflake. Contact your local security administrator.\n(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/4xp6)\nINFO:snowflake.con! nector.connection:closed\nINFO:snowflake.connector.connection:closed\n
```

Comment: How is this related to programming?

Comment: Lots of individuals post similar type questions for google cloud support: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-platform

Comment: Sounds like "Officer, there are others speeding as well!". Please note that there are other sibling site with special topics. Like [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) for example.

Comment: @KlausD. Pfffff

Comment: *"I still run into the error."* - what error ? Could you attach the error message you get to your question ?

Comment: @KlausD Google Cloud Platform has a link called "community support" that literally redirects to StackOverflow, so that's what I did. I don't think it's a case of "Officer, there are others speeding as well"; as a GCP user, I just followed their suggested resources

Answer (score 2):

Your snowflake application only accepts requests from whitelisted IPs which means you need to have a specific IP, or a set of specific IPs that are calling snowflake.
By default, GKE will not do this.

When a request from one of your pods tries to reach outside the cluster to contact snowflake, the pod IP is SNATd to use the node's IP address. Both nodes and node IPs are dynamic and stateless so you can't make sure specific IPs are used.

Instead, consider using [Cloud NAT with GKE](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/gke-example). This will ensure that all requests from your GKE cluster will use the same IP address. You can then just whitelist the Cloud NAT IP on snowflake.